# Extract link film by Html-Agility-Pack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I use `HtmlAgilityPack` to extract movie information on the web (as pictured) with c# winform on visual studio. But I can not get the movie link (as shown).
Please help me find a way to get the link highlighted in the picture.

[image]

```
HtmlWeb htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb()
{
    AutoDetectEncoding = false,
    OverrideEncoding = Encoding.UTF8  
};
htmlWeb.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36";
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = htmlWeb.Load("http://woohay.com/xem-phim/anh-2018-11458");
String link_film = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='jw-media jw-reset']/video").Attributes["src"].Value;

Movie_module.FrmVLC frmVLC = new Movie_module.FrmVLC(link_film);
frmVLC.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
frmVLC.btn_down.Visible = true;
frmVLC.Show();
```

Answer (score 1):

`HtmlAgilityPack` won't be able to extract dynamically generated DOM content.  I had the same issue when trying something similar.

I ended up using `Selenium`, which is able to traverse the dynamically generated DOM content, and it's also possible to leverage `HtmlAgilityPack` with content extracted from `Selenium`, it's not quite straightforward, but it can be done.

Comment: See also https://html-agility-pack.net/knowledge-base/41983000/how-to-get-dynamically-loaded-content-using-htmlagilitypack

Comment: `Selenium` with `phantomjs` driver is usually good enough. `PhantomJs` is incredibly tiny, but has a working javascript engine so that dynamic DOM gets loaded (usually) as expected. If the website is quirky, you can alway load a headless `Chrome` driver. That's a bit of a fatter dependency, but will always get the job done.

Comment: I tried using selenium, it helped me achieve what I wanted.
Thank you so much.